# PHP PDO Select and output first found row result

Tags: php, pdo, limit

after 1 afternoon of not finding the right direction I hope somone can help me.

What I want is: 
Bind an array to a PDO execute statement. Therefore I use the WHERE IN Statement in the PREPARE. So far so good, my Problem now is, nummer is not unique. In my database are more rows with this value. I need a way to limit the query to the first found row where nummer f.e. = 1 and then go to the next value of the array.

Here is the Code (I found here on stackoverflow ;)

```
$ids     = array(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9);
$inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));


$stmt = $objDb->prepare(
    'SELECT *
     FROM table
     WHERE nummer IN(' . $inQuery . ')'  
);

$stmt->execute($ids);

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  

        echo $row['name'] . "<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to add `GROUP BY nummer` after your `WHERE` clause.

```
$stmt = $objDb->prepare(
  'SELECT *
   FROM table
   WHERE nummer IN(' . $inQuery . ')
   GROUP BY nummer
  '  
);
```

**Edit**

For Postgres try:

```
$stmt = $objDb->prepare(
  'SELECT DISTINCT ON (nummer) nummer, *
   FROM table
   WHERE nummer IN(' . $inQuery . ')
  '  
);
```

Comment: I like the use of "nummer;" it's like "number" but quicker and it's got more twang to it.

Comment: But it's dangerously close to "bummer"

Comment: @Matt +1 for making me gurgle like a child :)

Comment: Especially at the end of "summer".

Comment: Hi Martin, yes this seems to be the way unfortunataly I get an fatal error using the GROUP BY …

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 FEHLER:

Any clue what´s going wrong?

Comment: Sorry only in German: 
Grouping error: 7 FEHLER: Spalte »table« muss in der GROUP-BY-Klausel erscheinen oder in einer Aggregatfunktion verwendet werden

Comment: … table has to be in the GOUP-BY-Klausel or used in an Aggregatfunktion (?)

Comment: Great! that´s it! Thanks a million. Seems I have misunderstood something about PDO. I thought this makes database unique syntax not needed anymore?

Comment: Nope, PDO is just a consistent interface - each DBMS has a different parser.